# gitignore directories only if they contain a special sub directory

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a directory structure with a number of directories which I want to ignore but the names are not unique but can be distinguished by a certain sub directory.

eg:

```
 +-a
 | +-d
 |   +-y
 +-b
 | +-d                 <
 |   +-x
 +-c
   +-e
   | +-a
   | | +-d             <
   | |   +-x
   | +-x
   +-d                 <
     +-x
```

I want to ignore all `d` directories (along with all content) that have an `x` subdir.
I do not want to ignore all `x` nor all `d` nor only `**/d/x`

Comment: You can't make *Git* compute that, but you could write a program that writes `.gitignore` files based on what's in the tree. Write this program in any language you like that *is* capable of reading directories and making decisions based on subdirectories therein.

Comment: Remember such a program can be ran from a git hook, to automate most of the process. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks You should know that git hooks cannot be adding to the git repo and ran on other peoples machines without they do something themselves.